SSL_connect returning error on certain hosts
I have the following code:
int main() {

  const char *host = "www.deribit.com";
  const char *path = "/v5/private";

  int port = 443;

  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  struct hostent *server;

  // Create socket
  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) {
      PRINTERR();
      return -1;
  }

  // Configure server address
  server = gethostbyname(host);
  if (server == NULL) {
      PRINTERR();
      return -1;
  }

  bzero((char *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
        (char *)&server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
        server->h_length);
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  // Connect to server
  if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
      PRINTERR();
      return -1;
  }

  // Initialize SSL context
  SSL_CTX *ssl_context;
  SSL *ssl;
  SSL_library_init();
  SSL_load_error_strings();
  ssl_context = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
  if (!ssl_context) {
      PRINTERR();
      return -1;
  }

  SSL_CTX_set_verify(ssl_context, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);

  // NOTE: assuming Ubuntu
  if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ssl_context, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", NULL) != 1) {
      PRINTERR();
      return -1;
  }

  // Connect SSL over the socket
  ssl = SSL_new(ssl_context);
  SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);

  int ret = SSL_connect(ssl);
  if (ret != 1) {
      PRINTERR();

      int ssl_err_reason = SSL_get_error(ssl, ret);
      printf("err reason: %d\n", ssl_err_reason);
      switch (ssl_err_reason) {
        case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
            printf("1\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
            printf("2\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            printf("3a\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            printf("3b\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
            printf("4a\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:
            printf("4b\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:
            printf("5\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
            printf("6\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
            printf("7\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("default\n");
            break;
        }
    return -1;
} else {
    long ret = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
    if (ret != X509_V_OK) {
        PRINTERR();
        return -1;
    }
}

printf("connected to host (sockfd: %i)\n", sockfd);

};

This code works fine and I make it to connect to the host.
But when I changed the host, for example using the following:
const char *host = "stream.bybit.com";

the SSL_connect function return -1, that by using SSL_get_error I understand that the error is SSL_ERROR_SSL.
What am I doing wrong? How can make my code working for any host?

See SSL_ERROR_SSL occurs while calling `SSL_connect().

... which probably means the site asked for a certificate, and you didn't provide one, and it needed one, so all it could do was close the connection.

In short: missing SNI extension, at least in this specific case.

Most related version (with the actual solution): Can't connect to host using OpenSSL in C++. Just adding SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, host) fixes the code.
